# When to init the NSManagedObjectContext?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I have an iOS app with master and detail layout.

In master, I managed my own `NSManagedObjectContext`, and also detail is, by this way:

```
NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *psc = ((AppDelegate *)UIApplication.sharedApplication.delegate).persistentStoreCoordinator;
_context = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
[_context setPersistentStoreCoordinator:psc];
```

In master, I display list that can be clicked by user to show the detail in detail layout.

Upon filling the detail by user, user can save the detail by clicking on button there.

However, I am trying to understand this:

- Since there is a save button in detail, the save method will **save the detail with detail's context and call the load list in master**
- Load list will remove all the `NSMutableArray` of the list `[_activities removeAllObjects];` and re-fetch the data from Core Data and reload the tableview
- Done that but the the re-fetch function seems to use old data and not the latest.

Why does re-fetch the data doesn't work if I use same context?

Comment: It's a little unclear, are you trying to refresh the list as it was BEFORE the user made any changes? Or are you saving the context first?

Answer (score 0):

You are using outdated APIs to create your managed object contexts. After creating a context, instead of assigning the persistent store, you should set the `parentContext`.

If you display a "list", you should be using a context that is of type `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType`. The best way is a `NSFetchedResultsController` which will also help you manage memory and performance, and greatly simplify the updates you need for your UI. (You would avoid the verbosity and complexity of merging the data "manually" via `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification`.)

*NB: Resetting the context is a crude and inefficient method for the task you are trying to accomplish. Due to the fact that it affects the entire context, it could change the behavior in other parts of your app.*

Comment: Looking from tutorial here http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/core-data-from-scratch-nsfetchedresultscontroller--cms-21681, it seems that the context is managed by application delegate? While in UIViewController, we use NSFetchedResultsController? However, looking deeper, it seems that I need to have different NSFetchedResultsController to manage several entities?

Answer (score -1):

You have two contexts going on here which is why the data is not being refreshed. If you call `[context reset]` then you will find that the data will refresh.

#### Explanation:

An `NSManagedObjedctContext` is a "scratchpad" which manages the Objective-C representation of SQLite (or XML) data in memory. When you fetch data the context retains the managed objects that are created by the fetch. If you then fetch from another context that context reads the data from the persistent store and creates new managed objects based on what it finds.

ALSO: When you perform a fetch the context checks to see if a managed object representation is ALREADY in existence and then returns it if it is. This means that two contexts can get out of sync quite quickly.

There are several ways around this:

1) Calling `reset` on a context returns it to it's "baseState" which means all the managed objects are "forgotten" or released by the context. Therefore, another fetch will force the context to read the data directly from the store.

2) Implementing the `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification` ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33667677/when-to-init-the-nsmanagedobjectcontext#33667677)) will allow you to incorporate changes between contexts.

I have found [this article](https://www.objc.io/issues/4-core-data/core-data-overview/) very useful in the past.